# Intrinsic index of item in a Powershell filtered item (using Where-Object for example)

Tags: powershell

Is there any way of getting the intrinsic numeric index (order#)
of the selected/filtered/matched object
from a Where-Object processing?

for example:

```
Get-Process | Where-Object -property id -eq 1024
```

without using further code... 
?is it possible to get the index of the object with ID=4
from some 'inner/hidden' Powershell mechanism???

or instruct Where-Object to spit out the index
where the match(es) took place?
(in this case would be 1, 0 is the 'idle' process)

Comment: As an aside: There is a conceptually related suggestion on GitHub to provide an automatic counter variable in the pipeline: https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/13772

Comment: right now I use a function with this this kind funcionality... something like: $a = Get-Process; $b = Get-Process[1024]: $a.IndexOf( $b ) // returns the 'complete' object you want... but again... it would be better to spit-out indexes from the Where-Object – 

PS: as someone already noticed... this is simplified for demonstration purposes... the function I use right now returns an array of all matched indexes...

Answer (score 2):

No, there is ***no* built-in mechanism** for what you're looking for **as of PowerShell 7.1**

**If only *one* item is to be matched** - as in your case - you can use the **`Array` type's static [`.FindIndex()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.findindex#System_Array_FindIndex__1___0___System_Predicate___0__) method**:

```
$processes = Get-Process

# Find the 0-based index of the process with ID 1024.
[Array]::FindIndex($processes, [Predicate[object]] { param($o) $o.Id -eq 1024 })
```

Note that this **returns a *zero*-based index** if a match is found, and `-1` otherwise.

The `::FindIndex()`  method has the advantage of searching only for the *first* match, unlike `Where-Object`, which as of PowerShell 7.1 always searches the *entire* input collection (see below). As a *method* rather than a pipeline-based *cmdlet*, it invariably requires the input array to be *in memory in full* (which the pipeline doesn't require).

While it wouldn't directly address your use case, note that there's **conceptually related [feature request #13772 on GitHub](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/13772)**, which proposes introducing an automatic `$PSIndex` variable to be made available inside `ForEach-Object` and `Where-Object` script blocks.

---

As an aside:

Note that while `[Array]::FindIndex` only ever finds the *first* match's index, **`Where-Object`** is limited in the opposite way: as of PowerShell 7.1, it ***always* finds *all* matches,** which is inefficient if you're only looking for *one* match.

While **the related [`.Where()` array *method*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Arrays#where) *does* offer a way to stop processing after the first match** (e.g.,
`('long', 'foo', 'bar').Where({ $_.Length -eq 3 }, 'First')`), methods operate on *in-memory* collections only, so **it would be helpful if the *pipeline-based* `Where-Object` *cmdlet* supported such a feature as well** - see [GitHub feature request #13834](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/13834).

---

Comment: I find the information you provide interesting and valuable... yet I would prefer not to filddle with extension methods or interfaces syntax inside Powershell as it is a bit clumsy... (I hope they'll fix this soon)...
as for the result expected... Yes... I have an array of matched-indexes returns (the function I use is a bit more sophisticated... I scaled down the example on purpose for clarification)

Comment: @ZEE, yes, it's obscure. Note that we're not talking about an _extension method_, because PowerShell fundamentally doesn't support them; also, the _cast_ `[Predicate[object]]` is needed to tell PowerShell's method overload resolution how to invoke this _generic_ method; support for generic methods is generally incomplete. The bottom line is that the `.FindIndex()` solution is far from PowerShell-idiomatic. Finally, obvious self-interest aside, if you found the answer valuable and think others will too, please up-vote it.

Comment: I appreciate it, @ZEE.

Answer (score 1):

You could capture the result of the `Get-Process` cmdlet as array, and use the `IndexOf()` method to get the index or -1 if that Id is not found:

```
$gp = (Get-Process).Id
$gp.IndexOf(1024)
```

Comment: I don't think the OP wants the process ID

Comment: @Tomalak Indeed, this returns the **index** in the array of Id's for Id 1024. That is what the OP wants isn't it? (_getting the intrinsic numeric index_)

Comment: No, it returns the process IDs (PIDs). :)

Comment: @Tomalak `$gp = (Get-Process).Id` returns an array of ID's. `IndexOf(1024)` returns the INDEX of ID 1024 within that array (or -1 if that ID is not present in the array).

Comment: No, it does not. It returns an array of process IDs, because the `.Id` property of a `System.Diagnostics.Process` object is its PID. Try `(Get-ChildItem).Id` to see what I mean.

Comment: @Tomalak with all due respect, I think you are missing the point. The code uses **2 lines**. The first gets an array of ID's `$gp = (Get-Process).Id`. The second line is what counts here, it finds an id by its PID in that array and returns the array **Index** for that item, not the PID.

Comment: The OP does not want the (index of the) process with ID 1024. The OP wants the 1024th object in the list.

Comment: @Tomalak I disagree. The OP wants the index for the PID: _Is there any way of getting the **intrinsic numeric index**_

Comment: Hm... I understand the "intrinsic numeric index" (the OP also called it the "order#") as what `for ($i; $i -lt $processes.Count; $i++) { ... }` would do: To count the items in an array from 0. This is the one thing that is easy with a regular loop, but difficult on the pipeline.

Comment: @Tomalak ..and the OP also states _s it possible to get the index of the object with ID=4_ To me that is asking for "I have an array of objects from Get-Process. Now I want to find at what array index the object with ID - 1024 is."

Comment: @Tomalak I guess only the OP knows for sure what it is exactly he/she wants.. Could be either way.

Comment: I use a similar (more generic solution)...
$a = Get-Process
$b = Get-Process[10]    // just to simplify the demonstration
$a.IndexOf( $b )            // returns the 'complete' object you want...

but again... it would be better to spit-out indexes from the Where-Object

;-)

Comment: @ZEE `$a = Get-Process; $b = Get-Process[10]` is not a good approach anyway, since the number of processes can change between the two calls to `Get-Process`.

Answer (score 0):

Or something like this.  Add a property called line that keeps increasing for each object.

```
ps | % { $line = 1 } { $_ | add-member line ($line++) -PassThru } | where id -eq 13924 |
  select line,id


line    Id
----    --
 184 13924
```